# Possible to remove a clone when dropped onto div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating an application that allows someone to drag clones of a shape onto a canvas and create a picture.

I want to be able to delete the shapes if they are dropped onto another div that is set to droppable.

Would this be possible?

```
$("#trash").droppable({
                    accept: '.item',
                    drop: function(event, ui) 
                    {
                        //remove the clone that was dropped
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delete just the element being dropped which is the clone by :

```
$(ui.draggable).remove();
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right. I wouldn't want to delete all instances of that class as other clones might exist. When a shape is cloned it is assigned the same class of "item".

Comment: your question states that you would like to delete the shape. So are you referring to the original shape, all clones, or just the dropped shape clone?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm referring to just the dropped shape clone.

Comment: i updated my answer... hopefully that's what you were looking for

Comment: Hero. Works perfectly. Thanks a million Tim!